# fast lookup with dictionary and pairs on series pandas dictionary map series

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series, lookup-tables

I have a matrix of distances 
A == > direct ==> B... Z

A == > via ALPHA ==> B...Z

B == > direct ==> C..Z

I have created a dictionary that works as follows:

```
#distances is populated with the distance value above
distances = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'From' : ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                                  'via': ['d','s','d','d','d','d','s'],
                                  'To' : ['B','C','D','C','D','E','F']
                                  'Distance': [10,5,12,4,3,22,21]})
distances_dict = distances.set_index(['From', 'via', 'To']).to_dict('index')
new_distances = dict()
for key in distances_dict.keys():
        new_distances.update({key: distances_dict[key]['Distance']})
print(new_distances['A', 'd', 'B'])
```

I have a pandas df (1,000,000 rows) where i am trying to calculate the distance for each row, but i will use the same as above to simplify.

```
a = distances
a['map'] = "'"+a['From']+"'"+",'"+a['via']+"',"+"'"+a['To']+"'"
a['Check Distance'] = a['map'].map(new_distances)
#yields NaN
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm looking at relatively large scale lookups of strings

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`a['Check Distance'] = a.apply(lambda x: distances_dict[(x['From'], x['via'], x['To'])]['Distance'],axis=1)`

Comment: I am trying to avoid using apply given the speed / performance is very slow. my dataframe may have 20+mm rows eventually